# Read 2-wire or 3-wire temperature sensor by unique connection to Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, temperature, wheatstone-bridge, rtd

I have 2 types of temperature sensors, 2-wire, and 3-wire RTD

I look on the internet and I've seen many schematics use the simple voltage divider for 2 wire sensors and the Wheatstone bridge for 3 wire sensors,

[image]

some circuits use an opamp in differential configuration to convert the 2 output voltage from the Wheatstone bridge to a single voltage which can be read by a single Arduino analog pin
my plan is to make a circuit
regards to the above schematics configuration for Wheatstone bridge its different for 2 wires and 3 wire sensor

My question is:

Is it possible to make a single 3 connections circuit that can plug in either 2 or 3-wire sensors?

Is it a robust design to use a voltage divider for the sensor pin for both configurations without using Wheatstone bridge or opamp and leave the temperature estimation by Arduino firmware?

Which of those schematics would be robust for temperature sensors?

[image]

the following schematic suggests a multi-sensor connection

an opamp on differential mode can compare the 2 & 3 wire temp sensor
in absence of a third wire one opamp input shows pullup fix input

[image]

Comment: I'd always use a current source for a 2-wire RTD and Wheatstone bridge (more linear)

Comment: As shown in the first group of diagrams you can use a 2-wire measurement on a 3-wire sensor, if you sacrifice the ability to compensate for lead resistance, which is maybe good enough for you.

Comment: To go the other way around, to put a 2-wire sensor in a 3-wire measuring circuit, you could just short-circuit the 2 connected wires with a little jumper cable in the measuring circuit's connection block. It won't sense the right lead resistance, but you weren't doing that anyway with a 2-wire device, so you didn't lose anything.